# Why do I get red color for some signals in simulation?

Tags: verilog

I want to do manchester encoder's simulation in verilog. Design code and testbench codes are written. Although I don't get any error, in the simulation part "clk" and "data_out" are not working which is red color in simulation but reset and data_in are working in the simulation properly. How can I correct the issue?

```
module manchester_encoder(clk,reset,data_in,data_out);
input clk;
input reset;
input data_in;
output data_out;
integer prev_data;
  assign data_out = data_in ^ prev_data;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
      prev_data <= 0;
    end else begin
      prev_data <= data_in;
    end
  end
  
endmodule
```

Its testbench

```
module testbench_manchester_encoder();
// Declare the signals
  reg clk;
  reg reset;
  reg data_in;
  wire data_out;
  
  // Instantiate the DUT
  manchester_encoder encoder(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .data_in(data_in), .data_out(data_out));
  
  // Generate the clock signal
  always #10 clk = ~clk;
  
  // Stimulus process
  initial begin
    reset = 1;
    data_in = 0;
    #20 reset = 0;
    #10 data_in = 1;
    #10 data_in = 0;
    #10 data_in = 1;
    #10 data_in = 0;
    #10 $finish;
  end
  
  // Monitor process
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    $display("Time=%t, data_out=%b", $time, data_out);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Red means the signal is 'x' , don't care or undetermined.  Tools like `lxt2miner` can be used to scan simulation for 'x' values.  You can also use this as a debug aid by forcing signals to 'xxx' where a subsequent block should always set them.  If a scan of simulated output show 'x', then there is an error.  `lxt2miner dut.lxt2 -c 2> /dev/null | grep x$$ | grep '^#[^0]' || true` is a make rule/command I use to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize `clk` in your testbench, doing that fixes your problem:

```
module testbench_manchester_encoder();
// Declare the signals
  reg clk = 0; // <------- here
  reg reset;
  reg data_in;
  ...
```